# Phone-to-Case Solution

Tags: force.com

Is there an existing solution in Salesforce for Phone-to-Case implementation? A client calls a 1-800 support number and the phone system should automatically create a Case in Salesforce?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the client leave a message, or talk to a call center operator?

Comment: The client selects IVR options and leaves a message/issue description.

Comment: I don't know of a packaged message-to-case solution, but you could build one with Twilio - it would be very similar to the [message to task](http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2013/09/transcribing-voice-messages-to-tasks-with-the-twilio-library-for-salesforce.html) solution I blogged last year.